# What should I do if my sensitive information is potentially leaked?

Tags: data-leakage, data-recovery, sensitive-data-exposure, identity-theft, data-breaches

I sold an laptop recently, but didn’t care to do a secure erase to make sure there wasn’t any data left. After a long time, I suddenly realized that I shouldn’t have be so careless and began to worry about my data since it could be easily recovered. My data is quite sensitive which includes: photo of my passport pages, photo of my study permit, photo of my credit card, and a substantial amount of my personal information. I definitely don’t know if the guy would try to get my files but I’m very worried and wonder what to do to prevent from bad things to happen.

Comment: Was the data on an HDD or an SSD?

Comment: It’s on an SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of information was leaked. Since you mentioned electronic copies of documents, it might be useful to replace it. Also try to change your passwords and various internet services and activate 2FA.

To avoid such situation in future, try to use disk encryption. For Windows systems the Bitlocker works well and comfortable.